# In Scipy Linprog, is there a setting that makes the results "nicer"?

Tags: linear-programming, scipy-optimize

I solved the following linear program with scipy.optimize.linprog:

```
result = linprog(
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    A_eq=[
        [1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 1]
    ],
    b_eq=[
        -10000, -10000
    ],
    bounds=[(None, -1000), (None, -1000), (None, -1000), (None, -1000)]
)
print(result.x)
```

And got:

```
[-4982.07750764 -5017.92249214 -2508.96124608 -2508.96124608]
```

This program has many solutions that are numerically "nicer" (have more round numbers), for example:

```
[-5000 -5000 -2500 -2500]
```

Is there a way to tell linprog to prefer such solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `linprog` will use an interior point method. This will give correct solutions, but they often don't look very nice. The simplex method usually gives "nicer" solutions. When we add the argument `method = 'revised simplex'`, we see:

```
[-1000. -9000. -1000. -8000.]
```

Still not unique of course, but it looks a bit better.